# Prove that if $(x_n)\to 1$ is a sequence of positive numbers, then for any real $p>0, (x_n^p)\to 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Suppose we already know the following:

> Claim. If $(x_n)\to 1$ is a sequence from $\mathbb{R}$, then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have $\lim{(x^n)}=1$.

And we want to prove:

> Theorem. If $(x_n)\to 1$ is a sequence of positive numbers from $\mathbb{R}$, then for any real $p>0$, we have $(x_n^p)\to 1$.

I came up with the following proof:

Proof. Pick a natural number $m>p$. Argue that we can construct two sequences: $(a_n)\to 1, \ (b_n)\to 1$ of positive numbers from $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the following: $a_n\leq x_n \leq b_n$, $a_n<1$, and $b_n>1$ for all $n$. We will have,

$$a_n^p\leq x_n^p\leq b_n^p, \quad \text{for all }n.$$

And since $m-p>0$,

$$a_n^{m-p}<1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a_n^m<a_n^p, \quad \text{for all }n.$$

Similarly, $b_n^p<b_n^m$ for all $n$. Combining the inequalities, we obtain

$$a_n^m\leq x_n^p\leq b_n^m, \quad \text{for all }n.$$

Via our claim, both $(a_n^m)$ and $(b_n^m)$ converge to 1. Thus, by squeeze theorem, $(x_n^p)\to 1$ as desired. $\Box$

I will now show that $(a_n)$ is constructible:

For each $n=1,2,\ldots$, let $a_n=x_n-\frac{1}{k_nn}$ if $x_n<1$ (where $k_n\in \mathbb{N}$ is chosen appropriately to prevent $a_n\leq 0$. More precisely, this is done by choosing $k_n$ so that $k_n>1/(nx_n)$)   and $a_n=1-\frac{1}{2n}$ if $x_n\geq 1.$

$(b_n)$ is constructed with the same idea in mind.

Comment: Can you use that $f(x):=x^p$ is a continuous function?

Comment: I'd add a little explanation for why $a_n$ and $b_n$ do indeed converge to $1$, and I think $k_n$ should be $k_n > 1/(nx_n)$. The rest seems correct to me.

Comment: For the case of $x_n < 1$ always, and if $k_n$ were allowed to  be non-integer, I could choose $k_n$ so that $a_n$ is constant instead of rising to $1$. I doubt the integer restriction fixes the base problem. You could fix this by being more restrictive in allowed values of $k_n$, but you might want to consider going with something simpler, like $a_n = \min\{x_n, 1\}$.